# How can I show that this shape is connected

Tags: general-topology

Is the following shape connected? My intuition says yes...but I cannot prove  it...any ideas please? $$\left\lbrace(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:{x^2+y^2=1,0<x\le1}\right\rbrace\cup\left\lbrace{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: 0<x\le1,y=-1}\right\rbrace$$

Comment: basic stuff from metric spaces...

Comment: I know about the example of the graph of $$sin(1/x)$$ but I cannot find something similar here...

Comment: this example looks similar to the disjoint sets $$(x,1/x)$$ and $$(x,0)$$ but in this case the union is disconnected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tsemo appears to have answered the question in the comments beneath his post, so I'll just slightly generalize and summarize here to record a complete answer.

**Suppose $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, connected subsets of a topological space $X$. Then $A\cup B$ is disconnected if and only if $\bar{B}\cap A = \bar{A}\cap B = \newcommand{\nullset}{\varnothing}\nullset$.**

*Proof:* First suppose the latter condition holds. We'll prove this implies $A\cup B$ is disconnected. $X\setminus \overline{B}$ is open in $X$, so $(X\setminus\overline{B})\cap (A\cup B)$ is relatively open in $A\cup B$.
But 
$$(X\setminus\overline{B})\cap (A\cup B)
=(A\setminus\overline{B})\cup (B\setminus\overline{B})
=A\cup\nullset
= A.
$$
Hence $A$ is relatively open in $A\cup B$. Symmetrically $B$ is relatively open in $A\cup B$. Hence $A$ and $B$ disconnect $A\cup B$. (This is essentially the content of Tsemo's comment on his answer.)

Now suppose $A\cup B$ is disconnected, say by open sets $U$, $V$ of $X$ with $U\cap V \cap (A\cup B)=\nullset$, and $(U\cup V)\cap (A\cup B)=A\cup B$. Then $U\cap A$ and $V\cap A$ would disconnect $A$ if both were nonempty, but we assumed $A$ is connected, hence one of these is empty, and the other contains $A$. Suppose WLOG that $A\subset U$ and $A\cap V=\nullset$. Then similarly, since $B$ is connected, and we can't have $V\cap (A\cup B)=\nullset$, we must have $B\subset V$ and $B\cap U=\nullset$. Hence $B\subseteq U^C$, and $U^C$ is closed and disjoint from $A$. Thus $\overline{B}\cap A =\nullset$. Symmetrically, $\overline{A}\cap B = \nullset$.

**The application to your question:**

> As for your case, the only point of intersection between the closures of the semicircle and the line segment is $(0,-1)$. This is not contained in either the semicircle or the line segment, hence the closure of the semicircle is disjoint from the line segment and vice versa. Thus the union is disconnected.

Comment: I think there is no need for the A and B to be connected in the proposition...thanks again

Comment: @dmtri, it was necessary for the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

draw a picture, it is not connected since it is the union of the half of a circle and a segment and they are disjoint.

Comment: Can you please tell me, where to cut it? the segment is tangent to the circle...

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the adherence of the segment and $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ -adherence of the half circle  check that that $U$ contains the half circle and $V$ the segment.

Comment: @uniquesolution, to whom goes the answer?

Comment: @uniquesolution But the two pieces are open in the *subspace* topology.  That is, if $$ X = \underbrace{\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 , x \in (0,1]\}}_{=:U_1} \cup \underbrace{(0,1]\times\{-1\}}_{=:U_2},$$ then both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open in $X$.

Comment: @Xhander the question is obviously about the plane topology, otherwise it is completely trivial.

Comment: @uniquesolution, the question is obviously about the subspace topology, or it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: That being said, both Tsemo's answer and Xander's comment don't actually justify that the pieces are open in the subspace topology, which rather seems to be the point of the question.

Comment: The interior and exterior of the circle with center $(0,1)$ and radius 2, for example, separate the semicircle and segment parts of $X$.  Or, for a more direct proof: for example, to show the semicircle is open in the subspace topology for $X$, notice that for any point $(x,y)$ on the semicircle, $y > -1$.  So, the open ball about $(x,y)$ with radius $y+1$ is disjoint from the segment.